# Close holes in Google Maps Javascript Polygon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

I have several maps with two polygons (red is a 30min transit isochrone and blue is a 30min drive isochrone) which are created as below. I am wondering if it's possible to fill the tiny holes in my polygon given the approach I use?

[image: Isochrone]

```
function drawCircle(point, radius, dir){
    // Function from stackoverflow
    var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians
    var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;   // radians to degrees
    var earthsradius = 3963; // 3963 is the radius of the earth in miles
    var points = 32;
    // find the radius in lat/lon
    var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d;
    var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point.lat() * d2r);

    var extp = new Array();
    if (dir==1) {var start=0;var end=points+1} // one extra here makes sure we connect the
    else{var start=points+1;var end=0}
    for (var i=start; (dir==1 ? i < end : i > end); i=i+dir)
    {
        var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points/2));
        ey = point.lng() + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta)
        ex = point.lat() + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta)
        extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ex, ey));
    }
    return extp;
}
function load() {
    var my_lat = 51.518175;
    var my_lng = -0.129064;
    // Custom formatting
    var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(my_lat, my_lng),
            zoom: 12,
            styles: [...
            ]
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < MARKERS.length; i++) {
        var name = MARKERS[i].getAttribute("name");
        if (name == 'transit') {
            var point_i = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(MARKERS[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(MARKERS[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            circles_transit.push(drawCircle(point_i,RADIUS_KM*(1000/1609.344)*BUFFER,1))
            bounds.extend(point_i);
        }
    };
    var col_transit = "red";
    if (circles_transit.length > 0) {
        var joined_transit = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: circles_transit,
                strokeColor: col_transit,
                strokeOpacity: 0.35,
                strokeWeight: 0,
                fillColor: col_transit,
                fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        joined_transit.setMap(map);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Funnily enough most of the posts I have looked through have asking HOW to create holes.

Comment: The holes means that you cannot  transit in 30 min.. fill is like hidden this situation..

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry I over complicated this. For transit I agree and don't want to do this, but for car I do

Comment: Just a question but how you get the data for the two isochrone. For what i know of google maps the hole are polygon in a ordered list after the main/first polygon. and should be possible get these coordinates..

Comment: @scaisEdge I have the full code at the end of my post here: http://iliauk.com/2015/12/20/isochrone-analysis-using-google-distance-matrix-api/

Comment: It seems that the holes are not holes in a polygon but the part not covered by the circles of isochrone (In this case  my ideas is not useful). But how you get the coords of the center of this "holes" ?

Comment: You will need to take your circular polygons and merge them into a single polygon.  Probably be simplest to do that with a GIS tool, although if you need to do it in the client, [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) might work.

Comment: @geocodezip very interesting library thank you! (I wanted to avoid arcGIS for this just for fun)